# How to prepend a lot of HTML elements with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, mongodb, express

I have a file sharing app for students written in JavaScript using Express, Mongoose, EJS as a template engine and AJAX.

In the app, I have an option for creating a folder. I have everything working correctly. The user clicks "New folder", then modal pops up where he writes the folder name and clicks "Create folder". The folder gets created and if it's successful I refresh users page by redirecting it to referer.

`res.redirect(req.get("referer"));`

I want to do that without refreshing the page though. So I wrote this piece of code:

```
// When submitting new folder form trigger an AJAX function
  $("#newFolderModalForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ajaxPostNewFolder();
  });

function ajaxPostNewFolder() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: window.location + "/new-folder",
      data: $("#newFolderModalForm").serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
        var html = "test";
        $("#newFolderModal").modal("hide");
        $("#materialsTableBody").prepend(html);
      },
      error: function (e) {
        alert("Error!");
        console.log("Error: ", e);
      },
    });
  }
```

With this code, a user clicks the "Create folder" button, ajaxPostNewFolder function gets called and because everything is successful an HTML text "test" gets prepended to a table body.

I want to prepend an entire `<tr>`element though, consisting of an SVG icon, buttons and name of the folder created.

In a different part of my application I did it like this:

```
var html =
      '<li>' +
      data.abbreviation +
      ', ' +
      data.name +
      '</li>';
```

One problem is that with the newly created folder, I would have to prepend or append a lot of HTML elements. If I did it the way above the html variable would get messy.

What's the preferred way of doing it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the same logic for appending `tr` and `td` elements for every property in your incoming data response.

Something like this would append a table row and tabel cells with any custom HTML (ex. `div`, `img`, `button`)

```js
const row = $('table').append('<tr>');
const cell = () => $('<td>').appendTo(row);

cell().html(/* custom HTML */);
```

You can also reuse logic for creating html elements

```js
const image = (src, alt) => $(`<img src=${src} alt=${alt}/>`)
const button = (text, onclick) => $(`<button>${text}</button>`).click(onclick)
 
cell().append(image('image url', 'image alt'));
cell().append(button('button text', () => console.log('button clicked')));
```